# Control-M scheduling changes

Tags: control-m

what all changes can we make in control-m job scheduling to minimize charges if we get charged on the basis of no of jobs ordered in a day in active schedule.

This is costing us a lot.

Comment: This is a VERY broad question. You might want to make it more specific.

Comment: we have around 700 control-m jobs that runs in our schedule. some jobs are daily,some are weekly and very few are monthly. we get charged from control-m on the basis of no of jobs we order on daily basis. is there any way to reduce charges by making some changes in retention of schedule or by any else means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex has mentioned, this is a broad area. And would be very difficult to anser to the point. But below are the few tips tht can be considered.

1. Check is the same script is being run by different jobs. This can be combined together by the help of scheduling tab.

2. File watcher jobs. If there is a requirement for checking the incoming file and then trigger a specific job for processign the file. [This makes up 2 jobs: Job1 - File watcher, Job2 - File Processing] This function can be achived by using AFT jobs. AFT jobs combine this two functions in one.

3. Low priority jobs, where alerting is not required, can be moved to unix/shell scripts if jobs are costly.

4. If Job2 is succeeding Job1, and Job2 is having only 1 IN CONDITION i.e from Job1, then rather than having two jobs, script (of Job2) can be called from the script (of Job1). So, ultimately we are doing two functions in Job1. Also, if the script (Job2) fails, then the Job1 will not get success return code. And you can get the details from log.

5. Keep the archiving functionality to the scripts and no need to bring it into the Control M jobs unless it is very important. And rather than doigni it every day for past 6 months, it would be better to schedule it once in a week or once in two weeks.

6. Sort the jobs in such a way that the regular jobs are in one table and the adhoc jobs (which is run only on request) into another. Keep the 'UserDaily' only for the jobs that are regular. Not keeping the 'UserDaily' for the jobs that are adhoc will not call these jobs in to the EM daily, and thus you see only those jobs that run daily and not the one that might or moght not run daily.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If some of your jobs are commands and share broad characteristics (nodeid, user, no alerts) then use conditional operators. E.g. linking commands with a semicolon will mean that each command is executed once. Linking with && will mean that the second command is only executed if the first runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctmudly command to order only the user daily you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using crontab in unix to schedule non-priority jobs which doesn't need manual intervention or observation. 
You can avoid the FW jobs by including file checker logic in your Shell script which executes the actual process.